# Modern 7.0 ComboBox fires 'select' event on every value change

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern, extjs7

The combobox in modern fires the "select" event every time the input changes. This is very different from classic. With it doing this there is no way to differentiate between a user making a selection and pragmatically setting the value of the field.

This was reported as a bug in the Sencha forums:

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?468730-Modern-6-5-2-ComboBox-fires-select-event-on-every-value-change

The link above also contains a fiddler to demonstrate the issue.

Has anyone run into this as an issue, and how did you overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forceSelection: true` will help to solve this problem but will not cancel the bug in cases when forced selection is not needed

Edit:

This behavior is due to method `syncValue` (search in this [source](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/modern/src/Select.js.html) - method is private and hasn't documentation)

I don’t understand why the component developer chose to create a record even if it isn’t exist.

Comment from source file:

> Either user has typed something (isInput), or we've had a setValue to a value which has no match in the store, and we are not forceSelection: true. We create a new record.

I propose to fix this behavior using the following override:

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/342j)

```
Ext.define('Ext.field.SelectOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.field.Select',
    autoCreateRecord: false,
    syncValue: function() {
        var me = this,
            store = me.getStore(),
            forceSelection = me.getForceSelection(),
            valueNotFoundText = me.getValueNotFoundText(),
            is, isCleared, isInput, value, matchedRecord;


        if (me.reconcilingValue || !store || !store.isLoaded() || store.hasPendingLoad()) {
            return;
        }

        me.reconcilingValue = true;

        me.getSelection(); // make sure selection config is flushed

        is = {};
        is[me.syncMode] = true;
        value = ((isInput = is.input || is.filter)) ? me.getInputValue() : me.getValue();
        isCleared = value == null || value === '';


        if (!isCleared) {
            if (me.getMultiSelect()) {
                return me.syncMultiValues(Ext.Array.from(value));
            }

            matchedRecord = (isInput ? store.byText : store.byValue).get(value);

            if (matchedRecord) {
                if (!matchedRecord.isEntity) {

                    matchedRecord = matchedRecord[0];
                }
            }
            else if (!forceSelection) {
                matchedRecord = me.findRecordByValue(value);
            }
        }

        // Either user has typed something (isInput), or we've had a setValue
        // to a value which has no match in the store, and we are not forceSelection: true.
        // We create a new record.
        if (!isCleared && !matchedRecord && !forceSelection && me.autoCreateRecord) {
            matchedRecord = me.createEnteredRecord(value);
        }
        else {
            if (isInput || is.store) {
                if (!matchedRecord && forceSelection) {
                    me.setValue(null);
                    me.setSelection(null);

                    if (!is.filter) {
                        me.setFieldDisplay();
                    }
                }
            }            else {
                if (isCleared) {
                    if (me.mustAutoSelect()) {
                        matchedRecord = store.first();

                        if (me.getAutoSelect() === 'initial') {
                            me.setAutoSelect(false);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        me.setSelection(null);
                    }
                }
                else if (!matchedRecord && valueNotFoundText) {
                    me.setError(valueNotFoundText);
                }
            }
        }

        if (matchedRecord) {
            me.setSelection(matchedRecord);
        }

        me.reconcilingValue = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response,
Yes, that does seem to stop the "select" being fired for every input change.
In my specific scenario I need forceSelection: true.
When I load the record into the form, I set the initial value of the combobox with a mock record. That initial value set fires "select", but it doesn't do that in classic. And I have controller code that works with both classic and modern, so the modern combobox is breaking my shared logic.

Comment: In my opinion most often in combo is useful `forceSelection: true`. That strange it doesn’t default value. Happy to help and welcome to StackOverflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: There are so many issue with the combobox component, its hard to pinpoint them all. Combobox is by far the component I have to override and change behavior the most.